# User name dropdown menu

Tags: sharepoint-addin, dropdown

I would like to have a input text-box to input user name and there will be some hints based on the user input. 
For example when user input Alex, it will come out Alexa, Alexb etc...
that based on the sharepoint user profile.
Any idea to achieve the goal?

Comment: how to add searchbox webpart to a page

Comment: Client side people picker can help you. https://saikiran78.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/jquery-plugin-sharepoint-2013-client-side-people-picker-control/